# Yesod Hamlet getHomeR can't find reference

Tags: haskell, yesod

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    wordList <- runDB $ selectList [] [] :: HandlerT App IO [Entity Vocabulary]
    defaultLayout
        [whamlet|
            <ul>
                $forall Entity wordid wordItem <- wordList
                    <li>
                        <a href=@{HomeR}>#{date wordItem}
        |]
```

I get this error

```
Variable not in scope: date :: Vocabulary -> a0
```

while I have defined in models:

```
Vocabulary json
    word Text
    date UTCTime
    deriving Show
```

PS: I'm developing based on the yesod scaffold example: yesod-postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `vocabularyDate` instead of just `date`.
According to the persistent section on the [yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent),

```
mkPersist sqlSettings [persistLowerCase|
Person
    name String
    age Int
    deriving Show
|]
```

will generates code which looks like

```
data Person = Person
    { personName :: !String
    , personAge :: !Int
    }
  deriving Show
 ...
```

As you can see, the field names are prefixed by the data name (`personName` instead of `name`). This is a standard practice in Haskell to avoid name collision.

Comment: may I know which part of yesod book explains this?